# Does SDL_SetThreadPriority work with std::thread

Tags: c++, sdl2, multithreading

I'm trying to set the priority of my threads so that my UI thread can be given priority over background calculations. I noticed that SDL has a `SDL_SetThreadPriority` method, however I still prefer the standard `std::thread` syntax rather than `SDL_CreateThread`. Does `SDL_SetThreadPriority` work with threads created with `std::thread`, or do I need to update everything to use `SDL_Thread`?

Comment: Have you run a test to find out? How did you test it, and what were the results?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would test it, is there anything visible you can see to see what a thread's priority is set to?

Comment: Presumably you could run a counter in multiple threads, then compare the counts they've reached some time later, no? The one with a higher count got more processor cycles, other things being equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some digging in the SDL source code, and seems like this might vary based on what threading backend you have SDL using. There is a `SDL_Thread` implementation using the C++ standard library, which like you said does not support setting the thread priority, so in that backend, SDL does nothing.

However, if SDL is running on one of the other backends, there seems to be valid implementations that fetch the currently running thread from the platform, and set its priority correctly. Fro a quick googling it seems that those backends match whatever you would get from `std::thread`'s native handle.

At least on window's `SDL_SetThreadPriority` is just a call to `SetThreadPriority(...)`, so it might be a cleaner solution to just write your own small wrapper, but using SDL should be just as valid if you make sure that SDL doesn't target C++'s STL threading library as its backend (which it at least for me automatically doesn't). Your own solution could also apply the priority to a specific thread instead of the current one, which at least to me seems like cleaner API design.